# Custom page template query_vars

Tags: wp-query, rewrite-rules

I created a custom page template `movie-page.php` and a page `movie` in WP.  The template shows fine when I visit **site.com/movie/**

I want to add `movie_id` as a query var.  Here's my code:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'poe_query_vars');
function poe_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'movie_id';
    return $vars;
}
```

I want to add rewrite rules so that **site.com/movie/123/** will give me movie_id=123. I'm not concerned with page numbers, although I could just use the `page` query var, I need to learn how to do this right.

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'poe_rewrite_rules');
function poe_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $custom = array('movie/([0-9]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=movie&movie_id=$matches[1]');
    return $custom + $rules;
}
```

I have clicked on Save Permalinks, and can verify that the rule exists. The rule is at the top of the rules, and lower down I see the others created by the custom page template.  In my movie-page.php template, I am echoing the rewrite rules, and the query vars and I can't get **/movie/123/** to give me a movie_id => 123.

**Edit** - adding the rewrite rules related to movie for reference

```
'/movie/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=movie&movie_id=$1&page=$2',
'/movie/([0-9]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=movie&movie_id=$1',
...
'movie/attachment/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$1',
'movie/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$1&tb=1',
'movie/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$1&feed=$2',
'movie/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$1&feed=$2',
'movie/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$1&cpage=$2',
'(movie)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$1&tb=1',
'(movie)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$1&feed=$2',
'(movie)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$1&feed=$2',
'(movie)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$1&paged=$2',
'(movie)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$1&cpage=$2',
'(movie)(/[0-9]+)?/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$1&page=$2',
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an *internal* rewrite rule, `$1` should instead be `$matches[1]`.

Comment: I've tried both, $1 and $matches[1] with the exact same outcome.  It didn't work.  I'll leave it at $matches[1] for now.

Comment: using your code and changing `movie_id=$1` to `movie_id=$matches[1]` works for me in twenty eleven theme, `movie_id` is accessible via `get_query_var('movie_id')`

Comment: also, a slightly cleaner method is using `add_rewrite_rule` hooked to `init` rather than manipulating the rules array directly.

Comment: thanks.  did you create a custom template, and a page named `movie` in WP?

Comment: yes, except I created a page-movie.php template rather than creating a custom template and assigning it, works either way though.

Comment: You're right.  I tested it with the twentyeleven theme and the code does work.  I'll have to troubleshoot what might be interfering with the theme I'm using.