# Custom page with queries returns 404

Tags: pages, query, page-template

My question is very simple. I created a new custom page template called `page-printable.php`. Then, I created a page with slug `printable`. If I access the page with `localhost/printable` or `localhost/index.php?pagename=printable`, it shows my custom page with no error. However, my custom page uses `$_GET` internally. But if I access the page with `localhost/printable?p_year=2018` or even with no-pretty url (`localhost/index.php?pagename=printable&p_year=2018`), instead of returning the correct custom page with the queries at `$_GET`, it returns a 404 not found.

Here is the code of my `page-printable.php`:

```
<html <?php language_attributes() ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Calendário</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta+Vaani:400,600,700|Roboto+Mono:500,700"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/frontend/dist/assets/css/main.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $query ?>
<div class="una-printable">
<?php

if (!empty($_GET['p_year'])) {
    $query['year'] = $_GET['p_year'];
}

if (!empty($_GET['p_month'])) {
    $query['month'] = $_GET['p_month'];
}

$query = !empty($query) ? "?" . http_build_query($query) : '';

$events = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://dev.unasp.edu.br/wp-json/custom_api/v1/printable" . $query), true);
$month_name = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'];

ksort($events);
foreach ($events as &$months) {
    ksort($months);

    foreach ($months as &$days) {
        ksort($days);
    }
}


foreach ($events as $year => $months) : ?>
    <hr />
    <div class="year">
        <h1><?php echo $year ?></h1>
    </div>
    <hr />

    <?php foreach ($months as $month => $days) : ?>
        <h2><?php echo $month_name[$month - 1] ?></h2>

        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Evento</th>
            <th>Unidades</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($days as $day => $events) : ?>
            <?php foreach ($events as $event) : 
            $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("{$year}-{$month}-{$day}")) ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo date('d/m', strtotime($date));

                    if ($event['end'] !== $date) {
                        echo " – " . date('d/m', strtotime($event['end']));
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $event['name'] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach ($event['unities'] as $unity) : ?>
                            <li><?php echo $unity ?></li>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach;
        endforeach; ?>
        </table>
    <?php endforeach;    
endforeach ?>
</div>
<script>
const fn = () => window.print()

if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" : document.readyState !== "loading"){
    fn();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I handle this?

---

As suggested by **Aadil P.**, I tried to use `query_vars` filter to add my queries, as the following code:

```
add_filter('query_vars', function ($qv) {
    $qv[] = 'p_year';
    $qv[] = 'p_month';
    return $qv;
});
```

I did not forget to flush rewrites in Permalink pages. Unfortunately, It didn't make any difference.

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `localhost/printable/?queryvar=queryvalue`?

Comment: @NathanJohnson Yes, I did. It also returns 404.

Comment: @MateusFelipe which queryvar exactly did you use? You may very well be messing around with the main query by reusing parameters that `WP_Query` uses, e.g. `p`, please update your question with a specific example rather than a placeholder like `example`/`foo`/`queryvar`

Comment: The exact query I used was `year=2018`, that is being used internally to filter results by year. So the full url was `localhost/index.php?pagename=printable&year=2018`.

Comment: `year` is a built-in query var that WordPress uses for date archives, you are unintentionally modifying the main query by adding that in the query string. You'll have to use something unique for your own custom query var.

Comment: I'm going to try it and give you a response soon.

Comment: @Milo I changed from `year` to `p_year` and nothing changed. I still can't access my page.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress rewrites standard wordpress urls from /category/post-name/ or whatever your selected permalink type is, into index.php?....

You are adding query vars to a link that is already getting rewritten into index.php?... and thus you are getting a 404.

My advice to you would be to use something similar to an already asked question at [Custom page template query_vars](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85427/custom-page-template-query-vars) or register the query vars properly in Wordpress.

Wordpress developer reference for adding a query argument -> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/

I believe that this should answer your question about **how you can handle this**.

Comment: Well. If I access `localhost/index.php?pagename=printable` it returns the correct page. Shouldn't `localhost/index.php?pagenanme=printable&otherquery=queryval` map otherquery to `$_GET`? It doesn't works.

Comment: Wordpress ignores query strings un-registered with it and hence that is why your vars are being ignored. [EDIT] - You should refer to this wonderful stack exchange thread I used some while back when I had the similar issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683666/wordpress-wont-keep-my-url-params)

Comment: I can't get how `add_query_arg()` will help me here...

Comment: I tried to add `year` to my query_vars as written in the link you passed and flushed the rewrite_rules, but still didn't work.

Comment: I believe that it's time to ask you to share your code .

Comment: I tried to give more info in my last info.